# ReactJS base64 file upload

Tags: reactjs, filereader

I have this function on a React component

```
handleChangeImage: function (evt) {
    console.log("Uploading");
    var self = this;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = function(upload) {
        self.setState({
            image: upload.target.result
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log(this.state.image);
    console.log("Uploaded");
},
```

and is called here

```
<input ref="file" type="file" name="file" 
                              className="upload-file" 
                              id="file"
                              onChange={this.handleChangeImage}
                              encType="multipart/form-data" 
                              required/>
```

I'm trying to get the base64 string to send via AJAX to a server running Flask.
The problem is everytime I select a file, it is logged as **null** in the console

Funny thing is, if I try to select the file a second time it now logs the whole string. I must be missing something simple...

Comment: What about multiple images?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is logged as null in the console because the state hasn't been changed at the time you print it out. When you select the file second time, the string logged in console actually belongs to the previous file you selected. The state is not yet changed to the second file you select.

Referring to [React's doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

If you want to print the correct state, you may log it in the callback function:

```
self.setState({
    image: upload.target.result
}, function() {
    console.log(self.state.image);
});
```

This will also work as the state should be changed after the 1s delay:

```
reader.onload = function(upload) {
    self.setState({
        image: upload.target.result
    });
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);    
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(self.state.image);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: How to get a preview box of image/file after its uploaded??

Comment: @isaksham To show a preview of the image, you can add this element:
`<img src={this.state.image} />`, where `image` is the file's data as a base64 encoded string. Whenever a new image file is chosen and read by `FileReader.readAsDataURL()`, the state will change and thus update the `<img/>` source.

Answer (score 19):

Try this one

Input field

```
              <MyTextField
                id="originalFileName"
                type="file"
                inputProps={{ accept: 'image/*, .xlsx, .xls, .csv, .pdf, .pptx, .pptm, .ppt' }}
                required
                label="Document"
                name="originalFileName"
                onChange={e => this.handleFileRead(e)}
                size="small"
                variant="standard"
              />
```

Read File from computer

```
  handleFileRead = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const base64 = await this.convertBase64(file)
    console.log(base64)
  }
```

Base64 Converter function

```
  convertBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      }
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      }
    })
  }
```