# "How can I efficiently send an image in base64 encoding from ReactJS to a Python server?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React js antd upload component send image base64 to the python server

Image upload send to the server base64

Without using formData method

Comment: Please go through[Reactjs BAse64 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580196/reactjs-base64-file-upload) this thread. It might help to find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need input `type="file"` to select an image:

```
    <input
        type="file"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
```

Function to convert file to base64:

```
const convertBase64 = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader()
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)

  fileReader.onload = () => {
    resolve(fileReader.result)
  }

  fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
    reject(error)
  }
})
```

And onChange handler:

```
const onChange = async event => {
  const file   = event.target.files[0]
  const base64 = await convertBase64(file)

  const formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('file-key', base64)

// --- now you can send base64 file to server --- //
  await fetch('api/{your-api-here}', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:   formData,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Please refer antd doc for uploading.
https://ant.design/components/upload

```
handleChange= (info: any) => {
 let fileList = [...info.fileList];

  fileList.forEach(function (file, index) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = (e) => {
     file.base64 = e.target.result;
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj);
 });

 this.setState({ fileList });
};
```